# Why django generates empty string after extend?

Tags: django, html, django-templates

My base template is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
    <title>{% block title %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        {% block sidebar %}
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Index page:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}My amazing blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% for entry in blog_entries %}
    <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ entry.body }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

What is wrong with that and why it is generating strange empty text inside those quotes?
It is affecting my layout. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last!!! I found what caused this.I use Notepad++ and encode to

> UTF-8

but I should have encoded to

> UTF-8 without BOM

Thanks everyone anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Does the source opened using `Ctrl+U` also look weird? Maybe it is Chrome that is messing up the Elements preview, because I have made a view rendering those exact two templates (and adding 2 dummy blog entries) on Django 1.2.3 and it rendered correctly as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head>    
    <title>My amazing blog</title> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <div id="sidebar"> 

        <ul> 
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li> 
            <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li> 
        </ul> 

    </div> 

    <div id="content"> 


    <h2>Test 1</h2> 
    <p>blah blah</p> 

    <h2>Test 2</h2> 
    <p>blah blah</p> 


    </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You are right, source is generated correctly but Chrome is messing up. When i try to render header with black(for ex) color i get small margin before header. When i delete this empty string in "Inspect Element" tab this margin disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attantion that your title tag inserted into body tag. Maybe start to search from here?

Comment: Are you sure that template index.html extends right base.html?

Comment: Yep, there are only two files, and resulting html is combined from those two.

Answer (score -1):

It can't be the result of this to templates combined, because in your "base.html" template, {% block title %} is in between  section, but in your resulting html, it is in  section. And also there's a CSS link, outside either  and  sections. I have lots of this empty strings, and this doesn't affect my layout, I think the problem is that your  is outside  section.